# When I try to get a quote for nflx my code tells me symbol does not exist. Below is my code. I can not find my error. Thoughts?

Tags: cs50, finance, quote

Here is the code to check symbol inputed correctly, then to show name, price and symbol on the quoted template.

```
@app.route("/quote", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def quote():
    """Get stock quote."""
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Ensure ticker was submitted
        if not request.form.get("symbol"):
            return apology("must input stock symbol")


        # Get symbol and make sure it exists
        quote = lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))
        if not quote:
            return apology("symbol does not exist")

        # to show company name, price, symbol
        else:
            return render_template("quoted.html", quote=quote)

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("quote.html")
```

Comment: This means that quote is falsy when you check if not quote. You'd have to also include the code for your lookup function as that's likely why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

IEX changed the API. You can find the new code for lookup function in helpers.py at [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/cs50/comments/mn193h/problem_set_9_is_anyone_else_having_an_issue_with/)

Comment: No, lookup() is correct in helpers.py.  Here is the command line output.

Comment: [Here is a list](https://iexcloud.io/docs/api/#error-codes) of iex api error codes. Look in the flask terminal to see what status is returned from the iex call. An invalid toaken returns a 403.

Answer (score 0):

No, lookup() is correct in helpers.py.  And I could get a quote from CS50 answer.  Is there some way to check if my token is correct?  I can log on to my finance app, but can't get a quote.